# How to use godoc to open the docs for your current package?

Tags: go, godoc

I want to display the docs only for a package. I've tried `godoc github.com/user/repo` as other answers says but I get the following error:

```
$ godoc github.com/user/repo
Unexpected arguments. Use "go doc" for command-line help output instead. For example, "go doc fmt.Printf".
usage: godoc -http=localhost:6060
  -analysis string
        comma-separated list of analyses to perform when in GOPATH mode (supported: type, pointer). See https://golang.org/lib/godoc/analysis/help.html
  -goroot string
        Go root directory (default "/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.16.5/libexec")
  -http string
        HTTP service address (default "localhost:6060")
  -index
        enable search index
  -index_files string
        glob pattern specifying index files; if not empty, the index is read from these files in sorted order
  -index_interval duration
        interval of indexing; 0 for default (5m), negative to only index once at startup
  -index_throttle float
        index throttle value; 0.0 = no time allocated, 1.0 = full throttle (default 0.75)
  -links
        link identifiers to their declarations (default true)
  -maxresults int
        maximum number of full text search results shown (default 10000)
  -notes string
        regular expression matching note markers to show (default "BUG")
  -play
        enable playground
  -templates string
        load templates/JS/CSS from disk in this directory
  -timestamps
        show timestamps with directory listings
  -url string
        print HTML for named URL
  -v    verbose mode
  -write_index
        write index to a file; the file name must be specified with -index_files
  -zip string
        zip file providing the file system to serve; disabled if empty
```

How should I use godocs to display only the docs for my package?

Comment: This error message actually gives you a lot of information. Did you try reading it or following the steps suggested?

Answer (score 3):

If you just want the command line help, do `go doc` or `go doc -all`.

If you want the browser version, it's a little strange. If your package is in a folder called `something`, you need to move the folder so that it looks like this:

```
godoc/src/something
```

Then, go to the `godoc` folder, and run

```
godoc -goroot .
```

Then, browse to `localhost:6060`.

Comment: Where should the `godoc/src` directory be on my GOPATH?
My package is in `$GOPATH/src/github.com/user/repo`

Comment: `If your package is in a folder called something, you need to move the folder` did you mean to `cd` to the package location on the file system ?

Comment: you can add a symlink of current directory to src for this to work: `ln -sf . src`. Remove it when you are done.